# Mac ports installation of gcc46 failing due to architecture problems

Tags: mac, macports, gcc

When trying to install `gcc46` on OS X 10.6.4 using `port` (MacPorts 1.9.1) i get the following errors:

```
artemis:foo$ sudo port install gcc46
Error: Cannot install gcc46 for the arch(s) 'x86_64' because
Error: its dependency gmp is only installed for the arch 'i386'
Error: and the configured universal_archs 'ppc i386' are not sufficient.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this or alternatively how to install gcc46 for i386?

Comment: Which version of OSX are you on? If OSX 10.6 how did you upgrade macports?

Comment: @Mark: 10.6.4 and i did nothing fancy - just a regular `port selfupdate` and `port upgrade outdated`.

Comment: Did you install macports under OSX < 10.6 and then upgrade the OS or a clean install of macports after installing 10.6

Comment: @Mark: I started out with 10.6 on that machine. Reasked btw on the [Apple Beta](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258/mac-ports-installation-of-gcc46-failing-due-to-architecture-problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly doubt you started clean on 10.6 as the default universal_archs would be "x86_64 i386" in that case. Compare and edit your /opt/local/etc/macports.conf to match with the sample which is provided in the same directory.

Then make sure all your ports are installed for architecture x86_64 following the [Migration instructions](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Comment: Yes, i am sure with what OS my iMac started out... For whatever reason though the `macports.conf` was the real issue, copying & editing the default one to the right archs did the trick.